# jQuery UI tooltip stops working in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I'm using:

```
jqGrid 4.5.2.  
jQueryUI 1.10.3
jQuery 1.9.1
```

In my jqGrid setup I do this:

```
gridComplete: setupJobStatusLegend
```

which calls:

```
function setupJobStatusLegend() {
    $(document).tooltip({
        items: '.has_status_legend',
        content: function(){
            var legend = $('#status_legend');
            legend.css('zIndex', 9999);
            console.log(legend.html());
            return legend;
        }
    });
}
```

It works great when I first hover over the rows--many times.  But when I click on a row or leave the confines of the grid, the tooltip never shows up again.

Any ideas on why it stops showing?  When it's working, it shows this for the console log line:

```
<img src="/static/img/circle_15_green.png"> Active<br>
<img src="/static/img/circle_15_yellow.png"> Hold<br>
<img src="/static/img/circle_15_orange.png"> Closed<br>
<img src="/static/img/circle_15_red.png"> Deleted<br>
```

When it's not working, it shows `undefined` for the console log line.

The HTML for status_legend is:

```
<div id="status_legend" style="position: absolute; zoom: .75; opacity: 1; background-color: #ffffff;">
    <img src="/static/img/circle_15_green.png"> Active<br/>
    <img src="/static/img/circle_15_yellow.png"> Hold<br/>
    <img src="/static/img/circle_15_orange.png"> Closed<br/>
    <img src="/static/img/circle_15_red.png"> Deleted<br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look like the dom is no longer found/or removed from document somehow. So I only can guess that
because Javascript use pass by reference, content object have been move around many times until somehow it have been removed.

can you try copy object?

try change:

```
var legend = $('#status_legend');
```

to

```
var legend = $('#status_legend').clone();
```